# How to create local STS for my WCF Service using claims aware Username/Login authorization?

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, wcf, wif

1. I have WCF services in need of claims-aware authorization (as in can-create-resource-X, can-edit-resource-Y, etc).
2. Authorization should be Username/Password based, no Windows identities.
3. I need to keep authorization logic and data local to server, where WCF services are hosted.
4. Authorization data should be stored in PostgreSQL and not SQL Server.

At first I was going to implement Claims-Based Security according to "Learning WCF. A Hands-on Guide", employing `pgProvider` as a PostgreSQL-based replacement for ASP.NET Membership Provider. But I stumbled over `ClaimsPrincipal` being redefined (along with `Claims`) in .Net 4.5 that I'm using now.

Then I came across WIF being recommended now as a primary device for authorization purposes. As of now I'm trying to wrap my head around WIF and I cannot find any mentions of a valid STS to be used locally. The only mention I came across is `Local Development STS`, but as far as I understand it is to be used for development and testing purposes only, not in production.

I considered creating custom STS, but according to google it isn't to be my first choice. And it does indeed seem an overly complicated approach for a seemingly simple purpose of having local username/password authorization.

So how do I go about creating claim-based authorization for my WCF services? Is there a local STS I haven't come across? Am I supposed to forget WIF and write my own authorization logic? Anything else?

Comment: Years ago I had a tutorial on active ws-fed profiles http://www.wiktorzychla.com/2011/09/quest-for-customizing-adfs-sign-in-web_2465.html but the problem is the tutorial is for WIF 4 and the api has changed since. Feel free to make use of this tutorial but you are on your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake.
`ClaimsPrincipal` mentioned in "Learning WCF. A Hands-on Guide" is not a framework class I thought it to be - it's a custom programmer-created class. I was misguided by a class of the same name in newer .NET framework versions.

Answer (score 1):

VS 2010 and VS 2012 had tools to generate a local STS but yes, not for Production.

The basic problem is that very few people used WCF (the WS-Fed active profile) compared to browser access (the WS-Fed passive profile).

So I don't know of any STS that you can use.

You may consider [Give your WCF Security Architecture a Makeover with IdentityServer3](https://leastprivilege.com/2015/07/02/give-your-wcf-security-architecture-a-makeover-with-identityserver3/)?

Comment: Thanks, I'll note this option. So far I ended up using GenericPrincipal instead of ClaimsPrincipal. Seems the most appropriate compromise for my scenario.